# JavaScript/jQuery string replace seems to work on regex101 not on script

Tags: javascript

I have a long string which I am using for filtering products. However, when a user uncheck a checkbox, I need to remove its value.

```
var filters = '.small, .medium, .big';
```

Now, with replace and regex I am trying to get rid of a particular value when the user uncheck a particular checkbox, let's say one with a value of ".small".

```
filters = filters.replace('/(, )*.small/g', '');
```

There could be a comma with a space just before the value, inside the string, so I guess (, )* is good for that. Let's just put our variable instead of ".small"

```
filters = filters.replace('/(, )*'+value+'/g', '');
```

When I put all of this in my js file, the replace function do anything, although I have verified on regex101 and it looks good. Did I forget something?

Comment: You don't need `/` characters in a regex string when you build it that way. The `/` characters are used for regex literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build up a string, which would replace that exact "/( ,)*.small/g" which you don't have in your string. Parse it as a regex:

```
filters = filters.replace(new RegExp('(, )*' + value, "g"), '');
```

But why don't you just keep the values in an array, than filtering is way easier...

Comment: I'm using a plugin that filters from a string, unfortunately!